# How can I install MongoDB on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-17.10

I found out that MongoDB does not provide support for Ubuntu's non-LTS versions. I tried installing the unofficial mongodb package provided by Ubuntu, however, it won't install successfully:

```
$ sudo apt install mongodb
[sudo] password for nabhoneel: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-program-options1.62.0 libgoogle-perftools4
  libtcmalloc-minimal4 libunwind8 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 mongo-tools mongodb-clients
  mongodb-server
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-program-options1.62.0 libgoogle-perftools4
  libtcmalloc-minimal4 libunwind8 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 mongo-tools mongodb
  mongodb-clients mongodb-server
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 1 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/48.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 183 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 288023 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server (3.0.15) ...
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried this method: [How to Install and Secure MongoDB 3.6 on Ubuntu 17.10 (on Medium.com)](https://medium.com/gatemill/how-to-install-mongodb-3-6-on-ubuntu-17-10-ac0bc225e648)

That didn't work either.

I'm not at all an expert, but the common problem seems to be with starting the MongoDB service. However, how can the service be started without installing it?

It would be immensely helpful if someone could help me with this, otherwise, I'll have to install some other (officially) compatible version of Linux.

Comment: it seems that mongo.service can't be stopped, can you review if there is a process about mongo `ps aux | grep mongo` if there is kill it and try installing again

Comment: I have it installed on my 17.10 ubuntu server so it's def doable. I don't remember how I've installed it tho, I'll check later on and post a comment when I can access the server.

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillas I tried that. I don't know why the PID keeps changing constantly. I can't kill it.

Comment: @HRK44 Okay. Thanks a lot! Please do.

Comment: @NovoBook My bad, I have 3.4 and not 3.6 !

Comment: @HRK44 still, could you share the procedure you had followed?

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps below:
open your terminal copy and paste the commands and press "enter" after each command you paste.

1. sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
2. echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

3.sudo apt-get update

4.sudo apt-get install -y mongodb

after the mongodb is already downloaded, copy and paste separately  (5), (6) and (7) just after when you see  "Setting up mongodb (1:3.4.7-1) ..."
paste it before the process terminate and press "enter"

5. systemctl daemon-reload
6. systemctl start mongodb
7. systemctl enable mongodb

Open a new terminal 'Alt+Ctrl+T' 
copy and paste (8) then press enter.

8. sudo systemctl status mongodb

you should see something like this

[sudo] password for fc:

● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset:

Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-06-24 17:08:59 WAT; 6min ago

```
 Docs: man:mongod(1)
```

Main PID: 29960 (mongod)

```
Tasks: 20 (limit: 4915)
```

CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service

```
       └─29960 /usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=/run/mongodb --config /etc
```

Jun 24 17:08:59 fc-HP-G60-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started An object/document-ori

lines 1-10/10 (END).

And finally your you mongodb is installed.
depending on what version you want, you can change the version at (2) to the version you want. e.g. change everywhere you see "3.2" to "3.6"